# Remove results from a linq query depending on query text

Tags: c#, linq

I have a method the search for files:

```
public IActionResult FilesContainingText(string query)
{
    //...

    var results = files.Where(f => f.FileName.ToLower().Contains(query.ToLower()));
```

This currently returns all files that contain the `query` text. However, there are a number of files that begin with "new" that I want to remove from the results list, but only if the `query` string does not begin with "new".

E.g. currently for the following files:

```
NewFile1
NewFile2
File1
File2
```

It would currently return all 4 results if `query` was "file", but only the first two if `query` was "newfile". What I want is when `query` is provided as "file" it should only return File1 & File2 in results. Hope this makes sense.

I have tried the following but its not removing the values:

```
if(!query.ToLower().Contains("new"))
{
    results = results.Where(x => !x.FileName.Contains("new"));
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to lowercase `FileName`. It should be `x => !x.FileName.ToLower().Contains("new")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the condition to account for your requirement:

```
var lowerQuery = query.ToLower();
var hasNew = lowerQuery.StartsWith("new");
var results = files
    .Where(f =>
        f.FileName.ToLower().Contains(lowerQuery)
    &&  (hasNew || !f.FileName.ToLower().StartsWith("new"))
    );
```

The added condition requires that either `FileName` does not start with `"new"`, or if it does, `query` must also start with `"new"` in order for the file to be included.

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/eWHSDn)